# Scrollview with autolayout programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, ios-autolayout, xcode7.3

I am trying to add 2 `UIScrollView` in the view. I have add one scrollview and it was working perfectly. Then I added other scrollview. But now it is crashing in first scrollview..

```
func setupTopModelScrollView()
{

    var viewBindingsDictBoth = [String: AnyObject]()
    viewBindingsDictBoth["shortListedScrollView"] = shortListedScrollView
    viewBindingsDictBoth["scrollViewTopModels"] = scrollViewTopModels
    viewBindingsDictBoth["contentView"] = contentView
    viewBindingsDictBoth["contentViewShortListed"] = contentViewShortListed
    viewBindingsDictBoth["lblTitle"] = lblTitle
    viewBindingsDictBoth["mainView"] = self.view

    scrollViewTopModels = UIScrollView(frame:CGRectZero)

    scrollViewTopModels.sizeToFit()

    view.addSubview(scrollViewTopModels)

    scrollViewTopModels.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    contentView = UIView()
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    scrollViewTopModels.addSubview(contentView)

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollViewTopModels.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[scrollViewTopModels]-0-|",options: [], metrics: nil,  views:viewBindingsDictBoth))

    let contentViewWidth : Int = arrTopModels.count * Int(SCREENWIDTH)

    scrollViewTopModels.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[contentView]-0-|",options: [], metrics: nil,  views:viewBindingsDictBoth))
    scrollViewTopModels.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[contentView]-0-|",options: [], metrics: nil,  views:viewBindingsDictBoth))

    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[contentView(\(contentViewWidth))]|",options: [], metrics: nil, views:viewBindingsDictBoth))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[contentView(==scrollViewTopModels)]",options: [], metrics: nil, views:viewBindingsDictBoth))

    scrollViewTopModels.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollViewTopModels.bounces = false
    scrollViewTopModels.pagingEnabled = true


    for i in 0..<arrTopModels.count
    {

        let topModelView = TopModelCell(frame:CGRectZero)
        contentView.addSubview(topModelView)

        let spaceFromLeft : Int = i * Int(SCREENWIDTH)

        topModelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topModelView.imgModel.image = UIImage(named: arrTopModels.objectAtIndex(i) as! String)

        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-\(spaceFromLeft)-[topModelView(\(SCREENWIDTH))]",options: [], metrics: nil, views:viewBindingsDictBoth))

        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[topModelView(==contentView)]-0-|",options: [], metrics: nil,  views:viewBindingsDictBoth))

        print(topModelView)

        contentView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Redraw

    }

}
```

I am getting this error and crashing..

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
H:|-0-[scrollViewTopModels]-0-| 
                           ^'
```

I am stuck.. If anyone can help.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The error sounds like your "view" variable hasn't been added to any superview. A view must have a parent before adding constraints.

Comment: after following @john_ryan comment you should follow this :> your "view" variable is not in viewBindingsDictBoth. So you must have viewBindingsDictBoth["view"] = view also.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. we need to declare the dictionary after adding the subview. otherwise it will take nill.

```
var viewBindingsDictBoth = [String: AnyObject]()
viewBindingsDictBoth["shortListedScrollView"] = shortListedScrollView
viewBindingsDictBoth["scrollViewTopModels"] = scrollViewTopModels
viewBindingsDictBoth["contentView"] = contentView
viewBindingsDictBoth["contentViewShortListed"] = contentViewShortListed
viewBindingsDictBoth["lblTitle"] = lblTitle
viewBindingsDictBoth["mainView"] = self.view
```

We have to write this code after allocating the all views..